# Suggested working flow in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I am trying to find out how to correctly use ncurses.
I want to create couple of menus, and each menu will lead to another menu for example.

Should I make a template of a menu then add parameter to the function of the generic menu that will choose which of the menu choices/size of the choice array/where it would lead to (using switch-case/if else)

```
gen_menu(1){...if (choice==1){gen_menu(2);}...}
```

or

Create a different function for every menu then call the function from each menu to another?

```
menu1(){...if (choice==1){menu2();}...}
```

Comment: You can use extension [library for Menus](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the ubiquitous "it depends"; both designs can be made to work more or less cleanly.  However, in general, I think the second organization is better than the first.

If you use data-driven menus, you will need a moderately elaborate data structure for each menu.  If the data comes from files (think I18N/L10N — internationalization/localization), then each menu and each item in each menu will need to be appropriately defined.  This can lead to quite a lot of code behind the scenes.  For simple menus (no I18N), you probably end up with a moderately elaborate data structure for each menu.  You can define those at the file level (static variables), or at the function level.  Your `gen_menu()` design looks like it will run with all the menu structures available to the single function.  Your `menu1()` design allows the menu structures to be defined per menu function.

If the menus are not data driven (for example, if you have a separate switch statement to handle the actions for each menu), then you should have a separate function for each menu.  Function size constraints should indicate that, if nothing else.  Functions that are many hundreds of lines long are not good.